# Not able to write the name of my shared memory to a pipe

Tags: c, memory, shared

I will admit, this is homework on a topic that is just not clicking with me, so more explanation focused answered would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to create shared memory for my multiple other process to be able to access given the name of the shared memory.  My other processes are connected to the parent process via pipes, I want to write the name of the shared memory to pipe after it is created.  Here is my code so far.  I never am able to make it to the print statement.

When I comment out write, the program will work once.  However, when I try to run the program again, I need to change the name of my name space for it to work.  I don't understand why that is happening. I'm sure there is a property of one of these functions I do not understand.

```
  int shm;
  char *p;
  shm = shm_open("Name",  O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  size_t len = 4 * 255;

  if (ftruncate(shm, len) == -1) {
    perror("Truncate");
    return 1;
  }

  p = mmap(0, 4, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);
  if (p == MAP_FAILED){
    perror("mmap");
    return 1;
  }

  write(fd[1], "Name", 30);

  printf("Initiator: Shared memory for Consonanats is %d.\n", shm);
```

Comment: Any resource that is opened should be closed when you're finished with it. You should `shm_close` your shared memory. That will likely get rid of the need to change the namespace each time you re-run the program.

Comment: The name of a shared memory segment should begin with a slash (`/`).

Comment: @Hypino, you seem to have misspelled "`shm_unlink`".  There is no `shm_close()`, at least not as a standard counterpart to `shm_open()`.

Comment: `write(fd[1], "Name", 30);`? Where do the 30 bytes you're trying to write come from?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to your `write()` call are inconsistent:

```
write(fd[1], "Name", 30);
```

You are attempting to write 30 bytes of a 5-byte array, which obviously overruns the array bounds.

Additionally, you are not checking the return value of your `write()` call.  In principle, a short write might occur, so that you need to make one or more additional calls to transfer the rest of the bytes.  Perhaps more likely, the write might fail altogether, in which case you perhaps want to take notice and do something about it.  Either condition would be signaled via `write()`'s return value.

Additionally, you write:

> when I try to run the program again, I need to change the name of my
>   name space for it to work. I don't understand why that is happening.
>   I'm sure there is a property of one of these functions I do not
>   understand.

Yes, there certainly is a property you do not understand: shared memory segments have kernel scope and persistence.  Among other things, that means that their lifetime is not limited to that of the process that creates them, and their names are global to the system.  That's why different processes can obtain access to the same segment by specifying the same name.

As @Hypino observed in comments, you never remove the segment you create.  In fact, you can't do that directly; instead, you must *unlink* it via `shm_unlink()`.  That disassociates the segment's name from the kernel, but it does not directly destroy it.  That would be unsafe, for other processes (or even the same process) may still be using it.  After being unlinked, the segment will be poised for teardown and removal, but that will only happen once no more processes have it mapped.  In the mean time, a different segment with the given name can be created.

The usual practice, therefore, is to unlink shared memory segments as soon as it is safe and practical to do so.  In effect, that means as soon as possible after all processes that need to map it (by name) have done so.  Segment mappings are per-process properties, so they disappear when a process exits.

In practice, it's unclear why reusing the name causes you trouble, however.  You should be able to open an existing shared memory segment left over from a previous run, unless you specify `O_EXCL` among the flags.  I suspect that that particular issue revolves something in the code that you omitted.

Also, with respect to segment names, do be aware that your freedom of naming choices is not absolute.  As the Linux manual for `shm_open()` puts it:

> For portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a
>   name of the form `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of up to `NAME_MAX` (i.e., 255)  characters  consisting  of  an  initial
>          slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.

Comment: You've taught me more in 3 paragraphs than my professor did in a whole lecture, thank you very much! Greatly appreciated.